# How to trigger Eclipse-like cmd+click in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

How do i trigger the `cmd + click` behaviour (Go to Class, go to declaration etc) in IntelliJ when my current keymap uses `Eclipse (MacOS)`?

I'm currently switching from Eclipse/STS to IntelliJ. So far, i've changed the keymap to use `Eclipse (MacOS)`, so most of the familiar keyboard shortcuts i use still works.

`control + click` does the functionality that i want using `Eclipse (MacOS)` keymap but this also triggers system behaviour of right click, so menu pops out the same time that the go to class/variable triggers. Is there a way i can set or use `cmd + click` to trigger the desired behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Preferences > Keymap`.
You have to copy the `Eclipse (MacOS)` keymap to a new name, in order to make changes: select the `Eclipse (MacOS)` keymap, press the `Copy` button and give it a new name, e.g. `Eclipse (MacOS) 2`.

Then click into the filter field, enter `declaration`, then in the tree area do right-click on the `Main menu > Navigate > Declaration` line in order to activate the context menu. The result should look like this:
[image]

Select `Add Mouse Shortcut` from the context menu, a dialog opens. Perform into this dialog the key + click combination you wish to add, in your case `cmd + click`:
[image]

Confirm the new Mouse shortcut with `Ok`, then close the `Preferences` dialog also with `Ok` or `Apply`. Done.

Note: you can delete the `ctrl + click` mouse shortcut, if you wish to not use it by mistake, by selecting `Remove ^Button1 Click` in the context menu.